# Batch Script service stop start issue on other server

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am wondering with a script ..

```
sc \\serverXXX stop serviceABC
timeout /t 2
```

I am running this from `serverYYY` .. how come this `sc` would login to `serverXXX` to stop service `serviceABC`??

Please help

Answer (score 0):

SC gives you the option to perform a command on \\SERVERNAME if you want. If you also want to pass a username and a password use this:

```
SC \\SERVERNAME STOP myService obj= Username password= Password
```

If you want to perform it on your local system simplay skip the servername.

For more information on SC check http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html.

EDIT:

To answer your question from the comments, here is the code:

```
SC \\SERVERNAME START serviceAAA obj= username password= password
:WAITINGFORSERVICEAAA
PING -n 10 127.0.0.1 > NUL
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a IN (
    'wmic /node:"\\SERVERNAME" service get name^,state /format:TABLE ^| findstr /i /r /c:"serviceAAA"'
) DO SET state=%%a
IF NOT %state%==Running (
    GOTO WAITINGFORSERVICEAAA
)
SC \\SERVERNAME START serviceBBB obj= username password= password
```

What this code does is start serviceAAA, then it waits 10 seconds and checks whether the state of serviceAAA is **Running**. If this is not the case it jumps back, waits another 10 seconds and so on. As soon as the state is **Running** it exits the loop and starts serviceBBB.

Comment: sorry didn't get you ...I am running this from serverYYY .. how come this sc would login to serverXXX to stop service serviceABC??   so in this case I am stopping serviceABC on serverXXX from serverYYY , I will be running the batch script from server YYY .. so do I need to give serverXXX login credentials .. if yes it will make sense , if no , then how come sc will login to serverXXX to stop the serviceABC     thank you.

Comment: I neither got your question. Could you paraphrase what you are actually asking and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Michael .. plz let me know if i am clear ;.. sorry for my english

Comment: If you want, you can add ServerXXX as a trusted User to ServerYYY and the other way around. This way you won't have to give credentials and each server will be able to execute SC command on the other one.

Comment: Mike .. can you imagine of a situation wherein serviceAAA has to be started before serviceBBB , so what extra parameter I need to add to make sure that serviceBBB starts only after serviceAAA has started ... 
will it be sth like this ..
I think it should check the port of its open by serviceAAA
sc start serviceAAA
waitfor NONEXISTINGSIGNAL /T 5
sc start serviceBBB

Comment: This won't work that easy because CS just triggers a service to start and doesn't wait untill it is up and running. You will have to use a waiting loop to check whether the first service is up. I will edit my answer and add the code for that.

Comment: Hi Michael..
I have made this script from your code..
==============================================
SC START QWAVE
:WAITINGFOR QWAVE
PING -n 10 127.0.0.1 > NUL
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a IN (
    'wmic /node:service get name^,state /format:TABLE ^| findstr /i /r /c:" QWAVE"'
) DO SET state=%%a
IF NOT %state%==Running (
    GOTO WAITINGFOR QWAVE
)
SC START PNRPAutoReg

Comment: E:\Scripts>SC START QWAVE
SERVICE_NAME: QWAVE
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 5732
        FLAGS              :

E:\Scripts>IF NOT ==Running (
E:\Scripts>

Comment: E:\Scripts>PING -n 10 127.0.0.1  1>NUL
E:\Scripts>FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %a IN ('wmic /node:service get name,state
/format:TABLE | findstr /i /r /c:" QWAVE"') DO SET state=%a
get - Alias not found.
( was unexpected at this time.